ggml-common.h not found compiling llama-cpp-python on MacOS
I'm learning about LLMs and RAGs.
Currently I'm facing an issue when trying to instantiate the llm using a MAC PRO with M2.
# Callbacks support token-wise streaming
callback_manager2 = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])
 
n_gpu_layers = 1 # Change this value based on your model and your GPU VRAM pool.
n_batch = 1 # Should be between 1 and n_ctx, consider the amount of VRAM in your GPU.

llmGPU = LlamaCpp(
 model_path="path/llama-2-13b-chat.Q2_K.gguf",
 input={"temperature": 0.75, "max_length": 2000, "top_p": 1},
 n_gpu_layers=n_gpu_layers,
 n_batch=n_batch,
 callback_manager=callback_manager2,
 verbose=True,
)

When I try to do it like that it gives this error:
"program_source:3:10: fatal error: 'ggml-common.h' file not found #include "ggml-common.h"          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ " UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=program_source:3:10: fatal error: 'ggml-common.h' file not found #include "ggml-common.h"          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ } llama_new_context_with_model: failed to initialize Metal backend

I've found on internet that installing llama using this command solves it:
!CMAKE_ARGS="-DLLAMA_METAL_EMBED_LIBRARY=ON -DLLAMA_METAL=on" pip install -U llama-cpp-python --no-cache-dir

But it doesn't for me. (I'm doing all this on a jupyter notebook.
Note that if I avoid using gpu layers and batch it would work but it takes 3 min to solve 3+3 so is too slow. I've tried using other LLama versions but still same issue.
I would appreciate some help! Thanks!

Consider installing llama.cpp via its Nix flake -- that way you're running the exact same build steps someone else validated with all inputs hash-addressed.

(yes, by default llama-cpp-python wants to build its own copy of llama.cpp, but you can turn that off; just need to be sure the versions are ABI-compatible)
